# Operating fails system when I execute a own program

Tags: pointers, wifi, ubuntu-16.04

I have a problem with my Ubuntu system, for a long time I am working in a program and since I compile this program my Ubuntu system has problems, it is not immediate happens it is progressively over time. When I turn on my operating system warns me about a problem with the Internet connection and sometimes, when this warning appears, I can't connect to my wifi. Over time this problem happens to me more often, arriving in the case that whenever I turn on my operating system, it gives me this warning and I can not connect to the wifi.
In my program I use pointers and I don't delete the objects that I create as a pointer (I am solving this), I think this is the problem.

So I want to know, is this the problem? If this is so, how can a problem with dynamic memory be related to a problem with wifi? if not, what could be the problem?

Comment: It's very unlikely that a program you've written would cause problems with the WiFi. Your program's memory is separate from the OS memory used for managing devices. You have a system problem.

Comment: But I think my problem is related with de program because I don't execute it for a long time and my computer works well. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you run the program as root? That's the only likely way that something it does could interfere with the OS. Anyway, without seeing the program, anything we say would just be total guesses.